# Docker daemon not start after OS update

Tags: docker, docker-daemon

Currently I've configured my docker usingn **/etc/docker/daemon.json**

```java
    "hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"],
    "tls": true,
    "tlscacert": "/data/certs/ca.pem",
    "tlscert": "/data/certs/server-cert.pem",
    "tlskey": "/data/certs/server-key.pem",
    "containerd": "/run/containerd/containerd.sock",
    "tlsverify": true
}
```

and **/lib/systemd/system/docker.service** on ubuntu 20.04 server

```java
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd
```

The problem is that every time I make an update of my OS, the file **/lib/systemd/system/docker.service** is overwrited and docker cannot start until I modify the file docker.sesrvice again

Are there something more that I need to do in order to avoid this issue or my config files are wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When making changes to systemd units, never modify the units that ship with a package (as they may be updated/replaced when the package is updated). Instead, use a "drop-in" (override) unit to override options.

Refer to [Control Docker with systemd](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/) in the documentation.

Override files need to be put in a specific location for systemd  to load them (e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf`).

The easiest way to create an override file, is to use `systemctl edit <name of service>`. For example `systemctl edit docker.service`. This will open an empty file with the correct name/location in your default editor, in which you can specify the overrides.

After saving the file, you can view all active systemd units for a service using `systemctl cat <service name>` (`systemctl cat docker.service`). If those look correct, run `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart docker.service` to have the new configuration take effect.